# Starting up Ion3 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ion3

How can you start up Ion3?

I installed Ion by apt-get.
I have the `exec ion` in my .xinitrc.
I get

```
>> Unable to redirect root window events for screen 0.
>> Refusing to start due to encountered errors.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you started another window manager before this one.  What's in your .xinitrc before the line exec ion3?  Is there a exec startkde, metacity or similar?

If this isn't enough info to go on, I need to know what window manager you're migrating from.

Comment: I am using a fresh Ubuntu installation so the window manager is apparently gnome. I have not used any other window manager. I have nothing else in .xinitrc than the one-liner.

Comment: If Ubuntu is your wm, do `ps -ef | grep metacity`, then `kill <pid of metacity>; ion3&`.  Does ion start ok?